# difference between 'psych::fa.parallel()' and 'paran::paran()' in Horn's parallel analysis

Tags: r, factor-analysis, parallel-analysis

I am trying to conduct an explanatory factor analysis for data with dichotomous variables([csv Google link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kIuf7pfjfEeNsLh9nDcaEYmpjMIzuaSW/view?usp=share_link), n = 1000 originally but only 500 here) with a WLSMV estimator using `lavaan` package, whether the data sample is suitable for the analysis or not.

I tried using Horn's parallel analysis by `psych::fa.parallel(df, fa="fa", fm="wls")` and `paran::paran(df, cfa=TRUE)` in order to decide the appropriate number of factors, but they gave different results.

```r
## psych
Using eigendecomposition of correlation matrix.
[1] 3

## paran
Parallel analysis suggests that the number of factors =  2  and the number of components =  NA 
[1] 2
```

Why did this happen? Also, why does `psych::fa.parallel()` need a factoring method as an argument, while `paran::paran()` does not?